# "Must declare the scalar variable" error in my created SQL trigger

Tags: sql

I get this error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@PlanIdTable"

but I have no idea where the problem is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[plan_status_trigger]
ON [dbo].[PlanTask]
AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF UPDATE(TaskStatus)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @PlanIdTable TABLE (Id nvarchar(20))

        INSERT INTO @PlanIdTable
            SELECT DISTINCT PlanId
            FROM dbo.PlanTask
            WHERE TaskId IN (SELECT TaskId FROM INSERTED)

        UPDATE dbo.[Plan]
        SET PlanStatus = dbo.F_computePlanStatus(PlanId)
        WHERE PlanId IN (@PlanIdTable)
    END
END
GO
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `@PlanIdTable` is a table variable, you also have to treat it that way. In the `WHERE` of your `UPDATE` query, you should select the `Id` instead of just using it directly inside the brackets:

```
UPDATE dbo.[Plan]
SET PlanStatus = dbo.F_computePlanStatus(PlanId)
WHERE PlanId IN (SELECT Id FROM @PlanIdTable)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a lot of redundant code in your trigger.

This should do the same thing - refresh only PlanStatus for plans that were updated

Be wary of performance issues here. Your updates to [dbo].[PlanTask] won't finish till this trigger finishes, and `dbo.F_computePlanStatus(PlanId)` is a performance red flag.

Also your existing logic won't work if for example a PlanId is deleted. I've updated the trigger to allow for this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[plan_status_trigger]
ON [dbo].[PlanTask]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF UPDATE(TaskStatus)
        UPDATE dbo.[Plan]
        SET PlanStatus = dbo.F_computePlanStatus(PlanId)
        WHERE EXISTS (
            SELECT * FROM 
            (  SELECT PlanId FROM INSERTED 
               UNION 
               SELECT PlanId FROM DELETED
            ) ST WHERE ST.PlanId = Plan.PlanId
        ) 
    END
END
```